# Efficiently create "key-key" pairs from "key-value" pairs

Tags: key-bindings

I'm looking for an efficient way of going from this:

```
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST=asd.sadas.dashasd
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS=False
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL=False
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER=asdash@hdushads.com
```

To this:

```
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST=${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST}
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS=${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS}
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL=${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL}
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER=${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER}
```

I find this a somewhat common task I do. Here's a similar use case:

```
var_1 = "apple"
var_2 = "pineapple"
val_1 = 0.5
val_2 = 5.2

return dict(
    var_1=var_1,
    var_2=var_2,
    val_1=val_1,
    val_2=val_2,
)
```

You can see how I would benefit from having a quick way to create the return statement from the variables above.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is best handled with `:substitute`

```
:%s/^\(\k\+\)=\zs.*/$(\1)
```

- on every line
- from the first column
- create a group of more than one consecutive keyword characters
- expect a equal sign
- start the replacement zone
- match everything there
- replace everything in that zone with the first group found, and a few characters around.

---

Regarding the second case, to generate very recurring snippets, a bit more work is required. (no need to bother usually, just get yourself familiar with `:substitute`, it'll also help you to with `sed`)

1. given a selected range, let say line1 to line2 for the sake of the explanation
2. [`getline(line1, line2)`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/builtin.txt.html#getline%28%29) will return the related lines
3. Piping (with `->`) to [`map()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/builtin.txt.html#map%28%29) we can keep `key=key`.
4. Around the array, we surround with `return ...`  and the closing brace
5. then either insert it back, or fill it in a register.... I'd go for the register as it will be easier to select where we want to insert the generated code.

This would become the visual (=> [`x`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map%2dtable))mapping

```
" <buffer> => expected to go in the right ftplugin 
" (python? -> `~/.vim/ftplugin/python/my_python_shortcuts.vim`)

xnoremap <silent><buffer> µ :<c-u>call setreg(
    \ v:register, 
    \ ["return dict("]
    \  + getline(line("'<"), line("'>"))
    \     ->map({_,v -> substitute(
    \                              v,
    \                             '\s*\(\k\+\)\s*=.*',
    \                             repeat(' ', &sw)..'\1=\1,',
    \                             '')})
    \ + [")"]
    \ )<cr>


" Or with  bit more of dark-magic to correctly print the register
" where it has been generated:

xnoremap <silent><buffer> µ :<c-u>echo printf(
    \    "Generated dictionary stored in register %s",
    \    [ v:register, 
    \      setreg(v:register, ["return dict("] + getline(line("'<"), line("'>"))->map({_,v -> substitute(v, '\s*\(\k\+\)\s*=.*', repeat(' ', &sw)..'\1=\1,', '')}) + [")"])
    \    ][0]
    \ )<cr>
```

In order to use it, select lines with [`V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#V), choose a register (`"a` for instance, by default it will be the [default *unnamed-register*](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quotequote) hit `µ` (or any other trigger of your choosing), go where you want, and paste back with `p`, (or `"ap` if you have selected register `"a`)

Comment: Very cool! Scratching my head about \k and \z. Also noticing how you need to escape characters I'm not used to escaping, e.g. (, +

Comment: Using substitute I can also do something simpler like this that be modified as per use case :`:%s/^\(.*\)=.*/\1=${\1}`

Comment: Yes indeed. Regarding the various atoms, check [`:h /\k`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5ck), [`:h /\zs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5czs). And indeed Vim has a different default regarding escaping. See [`:h /magic`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fmagic)